# SslRequireCert and Azure Web Roles

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services, client-certificates

My Azure Web Role (Cloud Services, not WebApp) needs to support Client certificates.

I've found that I can change the config of the website via included WebRole.cs snippet.  When deployed, the Client Certificate setting in IIS is changed (when I remote to the servers), but it is not working and I get authorization errors.  However, if I manually in the IIS manager click off/on the Require SSL cert and "Apply Changes", everything seems to work.  Webrole is running in the ELEVATED mode. What am I missing?

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
    try
    {
        using (var server = new ServerManager())
        {
            const string siteNameFromServiceModel = "Web"; // TODO: update this site name for your site. 
            var siteName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id, siteNameFromServiceModel);

            var config = server.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
            var accessSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", siteName);
            accessSection["sslFlags"] = @"Ssl,SslRequireCert";

            server.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle error here

    }
    return base.OnStart();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears that I needed to have plased SslNegotiateCert setting in as well, like so:

```
                        accessSection["sslFlags"] = @"Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert";
```

Comment: It was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the certificate in your Service Definition?

```
<ServiceDefinition …>
  <WebRole name="<web-role-name>" vmsize="<web-role-size>" enableNativeCodeExecution="[true|false]">
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="<certificate-name>" storeLocation="<certificate-store>" storeName="<store-name>" />
    </Certificates>    
    ...
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx